# UITableViewController warnings - Help !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So, I am posting my code below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     // I get a warning here Incomplete method implementation //
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSLog (@"Dobby4");
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.text = [dogArray objectAtIndex:row];

    //I get a warning for the line above-- 'text' is deprecated //
    return cell;
}
```

So,
1. I get a warning - incomplete method implementation for that function.
2. I get another warning 'text' is deprecated'
3. I tried debugging and tried to print a line "Dobby4" - and it DID NOT print.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Thanks for editing Deepak. Looks much better now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I doubt it is do with this function. Probably the method before. It would be good if you put that in the code listing too.
2. You shouldn't be using the `text` property to set the text (it is as the warning says, deprecated). Use the `textLabel` which is a subview of `cell`. So that line will be `cell.textLabel.text = [dogArray objectAtIndex:row];`.
3. Since it is not printing `Dobby4`, either your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` or `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning 0. If this is not so, then you haven't connected your datasource properly.

Comment: Hey Deepak, Fixed 2)  Thanks ! I tried debugging numberofSectionsInTableView by printing some random thing in the controller, and it did print. I think it is returning 0;

Comment: Implement both the methods I mentioned in (3) in the datasource. Return 1 for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and return `[dogArray count]` for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: When I return 1 from the numberOfSectio0ns. It works . Are there any concerns for this modification ?

Comment: TableView is about sections and rows in those sections. When you don't return a value, it defaults to zero. So no sections means no rows.

Answer (score 0):

1) The compiler could be moaning as the method implementation may not be present in your header file or vice versa?

2) the .text property of a UITableViewCell is indeed deprecated since iOS 3.0 so you will not be able to use it, seeing as you are definitely targeting a higher iOS version.

3) Perhaps linked to 1).

Hope this was of some help, keep us posted!

Comment: Krypton, With regards to 1) and 3) - Method implementation comes in the implementation file by default, and the header file is included.